# Can I Select a Border or how do I avoid breaking my listbox inheritance?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to change the color of some elements when they are selected and when the mouse goes over them. In my first attempt I am using a `ItemsControl` and a border to activate the color changes, this is giving me the change of color on the mouse over but I am not sure what property I need to trigger on for selecting it the `IsFocussed` as shown here is not correct:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Crp.CodePlusTeamExplorerSectionView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Crp.ViewModels="clr-namespace:Crp.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Crp.ViewModels:RelatedViewsViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Control.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="styleWithTrigger" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3E3E40" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#007ACC" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Control.Resources>
<ItemsControl Name="RelatedViewsICtl" ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedViews}" MouseDoubleClick="RelatedViewsLB_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Name="border" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" MinHeight="22" Style="{StaticResource styleWithTrigger}">
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="" Margin="1"/>
                    <Image Source="Resources\Review.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" Margin="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="-" Margin="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="1" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

The other alternative I have tried is to convert this to a `ListBox`, which seems like a better approach but the listbox stops my elements within from inheriting the correct properties, and I am unsure how to fix this

Comment: using ListBox with selection support out-of-box makes more sense. "listbox stops my elements within from inheriting the correct properties" - can you please clarify/elaborate this statement?

Comment: You can also override the System Colors. Which I really like when i want to do stuff globally. As you no longer have to use triggers or worry about events. You just set the SystemColor for a given Object and its "MouseOver" will be the color you want. [reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to select an item you should use a `ListBox`. A `ListBox` is a specialized `ItemsControl` that basically adds the ability to select an item.

You can then style the `ListBoxItem` container:

```
<ListBox x:Name="RelatedViewsICtl" ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedViews}" MouseDoubleClick="RelatedViewsLB_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="border" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" MinHeight="22"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3E3E40" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"  Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#007ACC" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Text="" Margin="1"/>
                <Image Source="Resources\Review.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" Margin="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="-" Margin="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="1" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This worked for the background, although I had to adjust the border to remove its brush. The foreground (color of the text) I had to set manually. I could not see how to make it inherit the correct color.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a list box, but the way the default ListBoxItem template is defined, it will override anything you set to its background values. This is likely the reason for your list box issues. An explanation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972818/listbox-mouse-over-background-color).

In short, anything you set to the background property of a ListBoxItem in the ItemContainerStyle goes unused since the default template triggers target the specific border in that template instead of the properties of the control itself. The solution is simply to **override the entire template**.

You can get to it quickly by typing in  in the XAML editor, select it and go to the properties tab. From there, under Miscellaneous->Template, you can choose to ["Convert to a new resource"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlud7.png).