# WPF changing background of ListBoxItem on mouse hover

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox, where I want to change the background of a ListBoxItem when the user hovers over it. Here is the code for the ListBox:

```
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Border Height="40" CornerRadius="5" Background="{StaticResource Maive}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MidBlack}" BorderThickness="5">
                                    <Border.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                        </Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource OrangeGradientBrush}"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Border.Resources>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="Age: "/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers> <!-- This is the relevant part -->
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MidPurple}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I've came across this question: [ListBox mouse over background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972818/listbox-mouse-over-background-color) , but I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the wrong element in the IsMouseOver setter. For a quick solution, you can give your border element a name:

```xml
<Border x:Name="MyBorder" Height="40" CornerRadius="5" Background="{StaticResource Maive}" BorderBrush="BlanchedAlmond" BorderThickness="5">
```

In the trigger, you can then refer to the name of the border element:

```xml
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <!-- This is the relevant part -->
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MidPurple}" TargetName="MyBorder"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```