# MouseOver And BackGround Color In ListBox ItemTemplate in Wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, mouseover, listboxitem

Hello I am Found Myself in a Problem. My Task Is when I Mouse over any ListBox Value The row and Line color will be changed . Please note that The Line Used using Border . I have found some solution in the internet but that does not match my code or logic . Here is My code

```
 <ListBox
        x:Name="listBox1"
        Grid.Row="5"
        Height="360"
        Margin="6"
        SelectionMode="Single" >
         <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate x:Uid="lititem"  >
            <DataTemplate >
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black" >
                    <Grid Margin="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!--<Border BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="0"
                        BorderBrush="Black">-->
                        <!--<TextBlock Grid.Column="0"  Margin="10,2,10,2"  Text="{Binding Path=傷病名}" />-->
                        <!--</Border>-->

                        <!--<Border BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black">-->
                        <Button
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="5,10,5,10"
                        Padding="5"
                        Background="#FF54CD54"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Command確定}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Foreground="White"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=確定IsEnableFlag}">
                            <Run FontWeight="Bold">
                                確定病名
                            </Run>
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Margin="5,10,5,10"
                        Padding="5"
                        Background="#FFFF5656"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=Command疑い}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Foreground="White"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=疑いIsEnableFlag}">
                            <Run FontWeight="Bold">
                                疑い病名
                            </Run>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>

                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>


        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

As You can see I used on trigger property IsMouseOver for Hovering and changing the background color to yellow but it is not working It is changing to different color. And also By using the <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> it also Breaks my Grid Column design means Grid Column style is not working as expected .

Comment: I think I found a solution Inside ListBox.ItemContainerStyle I put this link code and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972818/listbox-mouse-over-background-color

Comment: Why do you open 2 questions for the same answer? Then if it's working I only can advise you to close your 2 questions.